# local sqlserver connection with docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, connection-string

Hello I've recently added my existing .Net 5.0 Webapi to a docker container and it cannot connect to SqlServer on my local machine which the connection string is

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "default": "Server=.\\SomeInstance;Database=TestDatabase;User Id=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword"
    }
```

The exact error that I get is:

> 'One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific
> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
> server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
> name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
> connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is
> not valid))'

When I change it to `"Server=10.0.0.108\\SomeInstance;Database=TestDatabase;UserId=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword` It works correctly.

How can I keep the connection string generic to work with multiple developers/machines and still use Docker.

I have tried using `Server=localhost\\SomeInstance` it does not work.

Comment: So you are running  webapi docker container and you also running sqlserver on the same machine host and you are trying to connect from the webapi container to the host machine's SQL?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

`Server=host.docker.internal\\SomeInstance;Database=TestDatabase;UserId=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword` did what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the container is running its own networking stack and cannot address the host by `localhost` (unless you are using `host` driver for networking).

If you would like to keep the connection string generic, what you can do is you can add a [custom host entry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) to the /etc/hosts by running the container with the flag `--add-host [Hostname]:[IPAddress]` and then add the name in the connection string. This way you can manipulate the ip for the server to connect to at runtime.

Alternatively you can also use a special name `host.docker.internal` to address the host machine from the container.